# SQL MAX and same coupon

Tags: php, sql, max

I'm using this sql line to pull latest coupon:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `coupons` 
WHERE  `sku` = '123456' 
       AND `id` IN (SELECT Max(id) 
                    FROM   `coupons` 
                    GROUP  BY coupon) 
ORDER  BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

It's working good, but in rare situations when i have same coupon code on different sku the results is nothing.

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's happens when the higher id on the same coupon belongs to other sku so the results is 0

Comment: I think i solved it by adding where sku  = '123456' inside "IN"

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM `coupons` AS c1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT coupon, MAX(id) AS LatestId
   FROM `coupons` 
   where `sku` = '123456' 
   GROUP BY coupon
) AS c2 ON c1.coupon = c2.coupon AND c1.id = c2.LatestId
where c1.`sku` = '123456';
```

This way the inner query will give you the max id for each `coupon` and then the inner join will remove all expect those coupon with the max id.

In your query using `IN` predicate, you are comparing the max id for any coupon in the outer query, not only those max ids for each coupon.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM coupons c
WHERE c.sku = '123456' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 3 ;
```